# On derby with jdbc: creates a table instead of a view

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, jdbc, derby

I have a  JavaEE project in which I use the JPA. Because of JPAs limitation on creating views I used following code to send a plain SQL-statement to create a view.
The code works but in the database after commit there is a table instead of a view.
The same SQL-statement executed from within netbeans IDE creates a proper result.
Why is a table created instead of a view?

```
@Startup
@Stateless
public class Trans {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;
    InitialContext ctx;
    javax.sql.DataSource ds;

    public void sqlTest() {
        try {
            ctx = new InitialContext();
            ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/INCP");

            Connection connection;
            connection = ds.getConnection("incp_schema", "123");

            connection.prepareCall("CREATE VIEW \"SCHEMA\".LOGIN_VIEW AS
                SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORDHASH, GROUPNAME
                FROM USERTABLE, GROUPTABLE
                WHERE GROUPTABLE.ID=USERTABLE.GROUPTABLE_ID");
            connection.createStatement();
            connection.commit();

        } catch (NamingException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Trans.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're not executing your query. You create a statement with `prepareCall()`, You create a second statement with `createStatement()`, but you're not executing the statements. You should do something like that:

```
        Connection connection;
        connection = ds.getConnection("incp_schema", "123");

        String query = "CREATE VIEW \"SCHEMA\".LOGIN_VIEW AS
            SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORDHASH, GROUPNAME
            FROM USERTABLE, GROUPTABLE
            WHERE GROUPTABLE.ID=USERTABLE.GROUPTABLE_ID";
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute(query); // This is the line that executes the statement
        connection.commit();
```

I think you can also execute the query with `statement.executeUpdate(query)`, but not with `executeQuery()`, because it's reserved to `SELECT` queries that will return rows in a `ResultSet`.

Comment: My example is executed but a table is created with the given column names instead of a view.

Comment: I tried your changes but it creates a table too. Additionally I get a SQL-Exception with the changes.

Comment: You were right I had an other problem too in my project and because of that it did not work at first. Now it runs. Thank you!